# Retrieve Django hidden MultipleChoice form field value

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `ModelForm` like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    many_keys = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(OtherModel.objects.all(),
                required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    # i set this input as hidden
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        print(self.data.getlist('many_keys'))  # ['[1411, 1412, 1413..']
```

When I use this form to update the model, the `many_keys` is already populated with previous value, but unlike the non hidden field, getlist returns the value as a list of 1 string, instead of returning a list of primary keys.

In fact, in the HTML, the hidden field is represented like this, which may be the source of the problem

```
 <input type="hidden" name="many_keys" value="[1411, 1412, 1413, 1414, 1415, 1416, 1417, 1418, 1419, 1420]" id="id_many_keys" />
```

If I remove `widget=forms.HiddenInput`, all is fine and I get a proper list of primary keys. I found this behavior to be quite inconsistent, and I am searching a clean way to retrieve this value, if the field is hidden or not.

Comment: why not displaying it normally (no HiddenInput) but adding a `display: none;` to the parent element that holds this input in your HTML?

Comment: I tried `many_keys = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(OtherModel.objects.all(),
                required=False, widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'style': 'display: None'})`, that works but the label is still displayed. The form is auto-generated and i don't want to directly interfere with the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden only can have one value, if you want multiple values you have to use MultipleHiddenInput

[Ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#multiplehiddeninput)